# Proving Alternating Series Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Suppose $x_n > 0$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ is convergent.

Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx_n$ is convergent.

Any hints or starting points?

So far I figured that I should show that the terms of the series are bounded and decreasing.

Comment: One thing to notice here is that the Alternating Series Test cannot be used, since the terms of $(x_n)$ are not necessarily decreasing from some point on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do it by noting for any $\epsilon >0$ there is an $N$ such that $x_n<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$. Then we get, for $N<n<m$

$$|S_m-S_n|=\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m(-1)^k x_k\right|<2\epsilon$$ hence the sequence is Cauchy, hence converges.

Comment: @ Adam Hughes How did you get that $\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^ma_k\right|<2\epsilon$?

Comment: Triangle inequality.

Comment: @ Adam Hughes I still don't understand where the $2\epsilon$ comes from; could you please show this in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the general fact that if $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|$ converges, then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges also.

(See http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AbsoluteConvergence.aspx)

---

If you want to show this directly for the series you are considering, you can use
the double inequality $0\le x_{n}+(-1)^{n}x_{n}\le 2x_n$ for all $n$:

Since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2x_n$ converges, 
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n+(-1)^{n}x_n)$ converges by the Comparison Test;  so

$\;\;\;\;\;\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nx_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[(x_n+(-1)^{n}x_n)-x_n]$ converges also.

---

As an alternate argument, you could use the Cauchy criterion:

Given $\epsilon>0$, since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ converges there is an integer N such that $n\ge m\ge N\implies$

$\;\;\;\;\displaystyle\sum_{k=m}^{n}x_k=\left|\sum_{k=m}^{n}x_k\right|<\epsilon$.  Therefore $n\ge m\ge N\implies
\displaystyle\left|\sum_{k=m}^{n}(-1)^{k}x_k\right|\le\sum_{k=m}^{n}|x_k|=\sum_{k=m}^{n}x_k<\epsilon$,

so $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}x_n$ converges by the Cauchy criterion.